# Boolean value does not properly assign based on conditions in for loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am quite new to programming and VBA but I have been using a lot of help questions and answers here on stack overflow to learn! I am attempting to create a loop that will determine if a value from a "task" sheet is missing from a "preview" sheet and if so to add the number and line to the "preview" sheet from the "task" sheet. For an example of the data on each sheet:

Task Sheet

```
TASK VALUE  description 
11      task 1
12      task 2
13      task 3
```

Preview Sheet

```
PREVIEW VALUE       Description
1111                preview 1
2222                preview 2
11                  task 1
3333                preview 3
13                  task 3
```

The aim is to compare each number in the preview sheet to each value in the task sheet. If a value in the task sheet is not found in the preview sheet, then it should add that value and the entire line into the preview sheet from the task sheet.

My main approach was to create a for loop that would compare each number on the "preview" sheet to each value on the "task" sheet. If it found that two values matched, it would set the variable newTask = False  and then exit the nested for loop to move on to the next comparison. If it found that the value from the data sheet was not present in the main sheet, it would set newTask = True and run through until there was no more values to compare. Then, if newTask = True, it would copy and paste the value and line from the data sheet into the main sheet. This is my attempt at coding this:

```
Dim newTask As Boolean

iP = (Worksheets("parents").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 'count of parent workorders
iC = (Worksheets("child").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 ' count of child workorders
iT = (Worksheets("task").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 ' count of task workorders
iPr = (Worksheets("preview").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) + 1 ' this will set iPr one row below the last row on the preview page
nT = 0
Set prRng = Sheets("Preview").Range(Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 1), Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 11))

     For n = 1 To iPr

        taskWO = Worksheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1).Value

        For nT = 1 To iT
            previewWO = Worksheets("preview").Cells(nT + 1, 1).Value

            If previewWO = taskWO Then
                newTask = False
                Exit For

            ElseIf previewWO <> taskWO Then
                newTask = True
                End If

        Next nT


        If newTask = True Then

            Set tRng = Sheets("task").Range(Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1), Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 11))
            Sheets("Preview").Range(Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 1), Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 11)) = tRng.Value
            Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 12) = Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 13).Value
            iPr = (Worksheets("preview").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) + 1

        End If
    Next n
```

However, when I run this code, it keeps newTask = True, even if the values do match across the preview and task sheets. Debugging confirmed this and if it comes across similar values, it just continues over it as if they do not equal each other. This causes all values from the task sheet to copy over to the preview sheet, adding many duplicates. I also attempted a Do Until loop but get the same results: Here is my attempt at that:

```
Dim newTask As Boolean

iP = (Worksheets("parents").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 'count of parent workorders
iC = (Worksheets("child").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 ' count of child workorders
iT = (Worksheets("task").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) - 1 ' count of task workorders
iPr = (Worksheets("preview").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) + 1 ' this will set iPr one row below the last row on the preview page
nT = 0
taskWO = Worksheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1).Value
Set prRng = Sheets("Preview").Range(Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 1), Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 11))

For n = 1 To iPr
taskWO = Worksheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1).Value
    Do Until taskWO = previewWO Or nT = iT
        previewWO = Worksheets("preview").Cells(nT + 1, 1).Value
        nT = nT + 1
        If nT = iT Then
            Set tRng = Sheets("task").Range(Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1), Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 11))
            Sheets("Preview").Range(Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 1), Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 11)) = tRng.Value
            Sheets("Preview").Cells(iPr, 12) = Sheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 13).Value
            iPr = (Worksheets("preview").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count) + 1
        End If
    Loop

Next n
```

I have done a lot of searching but I cannot find any way to get this to stop duplicating values... but I apologize if I missed a thread that has this information or help.  I feel like it is something simple but I just cannot figure it out. Could I please get some help on how to correct this? If this is not the correct method, could you also please mention why the loop does not work or what went wrong so I can know in the future? Thank you for any help you provide! If you need some more information, please let me know.

Comment: Osheizer, I'd like to help you troubleshoot this because you've clearly put a lot of work into it. Any chance you have a sample of your data set to help me put it into context?

Comment: Yes let me look into how to properly post it and I will get it back to you! Thanks Jim (also, its Kyle! I thought I updated my display name but apparently did not!)

Comment: Kyle, for starters, with your line, "taskWO = Worksheets("task").Cells(n + 1, 1).Value"  'n' is not defined and therefor will always be 0. Which is to say that your line is the same thing as saying: taskWO = Worksheets("task").Cells(1, 1).Value. Was that what you intended, or did you mean to have that line inside your For n = 1 To iPr loop? Actually, I see that you have it there as well. Is the first line, then, unnecessary?

Comment: I did remove that line... thanks Jim. However, it did not fix it. I removed some of the debugging lines from the code because it really slowed down the code and I also added a small data set. Does that help explain what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Right, Removing that line alone would not have solved the problem. I updated the code in my answer in light of the data that you posted. Does that get you any closer?

Comment: Okay Kyle, I moved around the code in my answer a bit to fit you're updates. I think what I have there is a complete solution, or at least pretty close. I run it on my end and it seems to work. Let me know. -Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kyle, without being a complete re-work of your code, here's some code that I think might help you out. If I understand your problem correctly, the main issue you're having is that you're unable to properly determine if a value in one range exists in another. When I have this issue, I usually will use a dictionary object because it's fast, and provides an easy way to check if a value is in a list. To use a dictionary, however, you'll likely have to add a reference to it first. To do this, go to the tools menu and select "References". Scroll down until you've found "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and select that item. After that, the following code should run just fine.

```
Sub Testq()
        Set Dict = New Dictionary

        For Each Cel In Worksheets("preview").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            'Add the "Preview Values" of all the cells into your dictionary as Keys.
            'Set the value of each key to the "Description" which is in the row next to it.
            Dict(Trim(Cel.Value)) = Trim(Cells(Cel.Row(), 2))
        Next
        'Lets add in the header row of the task worksheet to prevent it from getting coppied over.
        Dict(Worksheets("task").Cells(1, 1).Value) = Worksheets("task").Cells(1, 2).Value
        'Now loop through all of the values in your "Task" table, checking them against the Dictionary
        'to see if there are any new ones.
        For Each Cel In Worksheets("Task").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Not Dict.Exists(Trim(Cel.Value)) Then 'We have a new value.
                TaskValue = Trim(Cel.Value)
                Description = Trim(Worksheets("Task").Cells(Cel.Row(), 2))
                Debug.Print "Yup, I found one that's missing: " & Trim(TaskValue)

                'Now add the missing value to the end of your "preview" sheet.
                LastRow = Worksheets("preview").Cells(Range("A:A").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Worksheets("preview").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Trim(TaskValue)
                Worksheets("preview").Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = Trim(Description)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Since you mentioned that you're new to VBA, I'll point out that to view the output of the Debug.Print statement, you'll need to display the "Immediate" window. Do this by selecting it from the View menu. As I get a clearer picture of your project, I'll supplement this answer as needed, but for now I hope this will help you solve much of the problem you're having.

Comment: The dictionary object is new to me so let me make sure I am getting this straight. So what is doing in the first part is making a list of all the values in the Task sheet as keys and then setting the description as their value. And then it compares this list to each cell in column one in the preview sheet by looping through each cell in the preview sheet. If a value in the dictionary (Dict.Exists(Cel.Value)) exists in the preview sheet, then it should print out the messages in that if statement, correct? It looks like it is not able to match them so it just cycles through  the for loop.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly right Kyle. I re-worked it a bit to load the preview values in as keys, and then search the tasks for values that are not in the dictionary. If it finds such a value, then it adds it to the preview sheet.

Comment: @Kyle Okay. Added one more line of code to prevent the column header from being copied over.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Jim! However, when I inserted the code into main spreadsheet, its still counting task values that are already on the preview sheet as missing and is then repopulating them. Its like 1111 <> 1111, which does not make sense. With that said, this method is much faster.

Comment: @Kyle Check to see if any of your values have spaces after or before them. In fact, maybe just to be safe, add .Trim() to the end of things. 9 times out of 10 that solves the issue. I update the code and see if that helps.

Comment: @Kyle Oh bother, I'm still thinking in C#. I meant Trim(String) rather than String.Trim. I made the changes. See if it helps.

Comment: It worked! So it was spaces after the number? The data is coming from a Microsoft Query, so maybe it is the way it is pulling over from the database. Either way, thank you so much Jim. Ill need to do some modification but it should definitely be doable now.

Comment: @Kyle. Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your project.